# How to access a view from a laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-blade, packagist

I'm working on a custom package to manage the licensing of my team projects, the problem I'm facing right now is to access the LicenseExpired view through the router, everything else works fine.

Here is the package structure:

[image]

You can see more on GitHub: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/omarlamin01/Lamine-License)

Here is the content of `Routes/index.php`:

```
Route::get('/activate-product', function () {
    return view('LicenseExpired');
})->name('license');

Route::post('/activate-product', [Index::class, 'webStore'])->name('license.store');

Route::post('api/license', [Index::class, 'store']);
```

the content of `LicenseServiceProvider`:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        // Load migrations
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/Migrations');

        // Load views
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/Views', 'Lamine/License');

        // Load Routes
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/Routes/index.php');

        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/Migrations' => database_path('migrations'),
        ], 'migrations');

        // publish routes
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/Routes/index.php' => base_path('routes/license.php'),
        ], 'routes');

        // publish views
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/Views' => resource_path('views'),
        ], 'views');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this? How is your problem related to Packagist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory structure for your package does not follow conventions. Views should be in a `resources/views` folder in the root of your project. In the `boot()` method of your service provider you should then do this:

```php
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', 'license');
}
```

You can then use the views from the package by using the namespace `license`:

```php
Route::get('/activate-product', function () {
    return view('license::LicenseExpired');
})->name('license');
```